# handle input box in map using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<input
  type="text"
  id={`order_${i}`}
  name={`order_${i}`}
  style={{
    width: "50px",
    borderRadius: "100px",
    border: "none",
    textAlign: "center",
    background: "#d7eefc",
  }}
  value={sortOrder || folder.sort_order}
  onChange={(e) => setSortOrder(e.target.value)}
/>;
```

if i change any one value of input box then it is update all input box value in map

Comment: Please explain your problem more in detail. For now it is not possible to help with this little information

Comment: when i change any one input box value in the map then it is changing all input box value which is in the map

Comment: But what map? There is no map shown, so I struggle to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions based on incomplete code:

As `` id={`order_${i}`} `` attribute is used, I assume this input could be a part of a loop. So the issue here could be same value `sortOrder || folder.sort_order` is passed to all inputs in the loop. Hence when this value is updated it may be getting updated in all the inputs. In this case, you will need to use an array of values something like

```js
value={sortOrder[i]}
```

and while setting the value

```js
onChange={(e) => { 
  sortOrder[i] = e.target.value; 
  setSortOrder(...sortOrder); 
}}
```

Comment: If you are assuming that `sortOrder` is a React state then this solution mutates the state which is a React anti-pattern and should be avoided. OP hasn't provided enough context to really say much about the code they *did* share though, so probably best to not make assumptions about what is going on around that code.